# Браузер не реагирует на имитацию нажатия клавиш

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver

Необходимо закрыть текущую вкладку в браузере. Пытаюсь сделать это через имитацию нажатия клавиш `"Ctrl"+"w"`.
Пишу код, но браузер не выполняет эти действия.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(Driver);
            actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys("w").KeyUp(Keys.Control).Build().Perform();
```

В чём может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tabs = driver.WindowHandles; // находим все хендлы табов
if (tabs.Count > 1)
{
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[1]); //переключаемся на таб который нужно закрыть
    driver.Close(); //закрываем
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[0]); // делаем иной таб активным
}
```

код найден по запросу "selenium webdriver close tab"